# How to get a ALL the css properties set on an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know that I can get a specific property

```
$('somediv').css('position')
```

But I want to get all of the properties that are set on `$('somediv')`

What I'm trying to do is create an entry in a .css file based on `$('somediv')`. I won't know what styles will be set on `$('somediv')` so I'm looking for a way to get all the styles with out explicitly requesting each one.

Comment: Use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Sounds like an x/y problem to me? Why would you create entries in css files based on styles the element already have.

Comment: Because you are talking about creating a CSS entry in a file, maybe you can consider using a browser extension / add-in rather than trying to the detail you seek using code.  The following is a link to a free chrome extension that I use for that purpose: http://selectorgadget.com/

Comment: @adeneo it's a template, styles are applied and saved

Comment: @SamLuther but many style properties will be inherited...doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you wanting to parse inline styles?

Comment: @charlietfl na, it makes sense. I think the possible duplicate of this question is the solution I'm looking for smarty pantz :)